# Fetching Facebook attachment using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a Facebook message with an attachment.

When I fetch the Facebook messages in my application using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox` the response doesn't have the attachment of the message.

Can some one help me to get the attachment of my Facebook in my application?

Answer (score 0):

Access the thread at `/<THREAD ID>/messages` and the attachments are visible there

Comment: <THREAD ID>/messages is returning "error": { "message": "Unsupported get request.", "type": "GraphMethodException", "code": 100 } . Can some one pls help me.